# Unit Test for Api

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to write unit test for the `api` which brings list of data. The `api` can onyl be accesses if user is logged in.

As i am new to unit test, i have no idea how to do this. Following is code which i tried till now.

routes.js

```
app.get('/api/practices/page/:pagenum', middleware.auth, practices.index);
```

testpractice.js

```
describe('Practice Service API to check authentication', function() {

    var httpBackend,
        serviceUrl = '/api/practices/page/?pagenum=1';

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');

        inject(function ($httpBackend) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        });
    });

    // check to see if User is Authenticated
    it('should have an authenticated user', function() {
        // To get response if user is not authenticated
        //serviceUrl.expectGET(serviceUrl).respond();

    });

});
```

How to exactly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a some very contrived pseudo-ish code based on the small info you gave. I hope it can get you started at least!

```
describe('Practice Service API to check authentication', function() {

    var httpBackend,
        yourService,
        yourResponse;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, ServiceNameHere) {
        yourService = ServiceNameHere;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/practices/page/:pagenum').respond(yourResponse);
    }));


    describe('Your Service Functionality', function () {
        // check to see if User is Authenticated
        it('should have an authenticated user', function() {
            yourService.methodToCheckLogin();
            expect('someexpectation of login events').toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```